# SQL Server: What's wrong with this dynamic pivot?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying to create a dynamic pivot but it keeps telling me "you must declare the table variable @venta".

Here is the code, what am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @venta TABLE
(
    LAPSO_DOC CHAR(6),
    ID_EXT_ITM CHAR(3),
    ID_TALLA CHAR(6),
    VENTA INT
)

INSERT INTO @venta
VALUES 
('201601', 'VER', 'L', '20'),
('201603', 'ROJ', 'XL', '40'),
('201604', 'NEG', 'S', '60'),
('201608', 'BLA', 'M', '80');


DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @columns=STUFF ((SELECT DISTINCT'],['+ LAPSO_DOC
    FROM @venta
    GROUP BY '],['+LAPSO_DOC FOR XML PATH('') ),1,2,'')+']'

    SET @sql = 'SELECT
    (
        SELECT LAPSO_DOC,ID_EXT_ITM,ID_TALLA,VENTA 
        FROM @venta
) 
PIVOT
(
  SUM(CANTIDAD_CAP) FOR LAPSO_DOC IN ('+@columns+')
) AS y;';
EXECUTE (@sql)
```

Comment: change your table variable to temp table; or it can also work if you have table type defined in db

Comment: even if you replace, your query seems will not work as it has inherent logic problems; you may better describe what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more problems with your query than you expect...

```
CREATE TABLE #venta (
    LAPSO_DOC char(6),
    ID_EXT_ITM char(3),
    ID_TALLA char(6),
    VENTA int
)

INSERT INTO #venta
    VALUES ('201601', 'VER', 'L', '20'),
    ('201603', 'ROJ', 'XL', '40'),
    ('201604', 'NEG', 'S', '60'),
    ('201608', 'BLA', 'M', '80');


DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max);
SELECT
    @columns = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
        '],[' + LAPSO_DOC
    FROM #venta
    GROUP BY '],[' + LAPSO_DOC
    FOR xml PATH (''))
    , 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @sql = 'SELECT ID_EXT_ITM,ID_TALLA,' + @columns + '
            FROM #venta
            PIVOT
            (
              SUM(VENTA) FOR LAPSO_DOC IN (' + @columns + ')
            ) AS y;';


EXEC (@sql)

DROP TABLE #venta
```

1. As @John Cappelletti stated, you can't use table variable in a dynamic SQL; unless you have a `Table type` defined in database or move to a `Temp` table.
2. There is error in your logic.  I'm quite not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the above code gives you error-free output.
3. You don't have `CANTIDAD_CAP` column anywhere defined but used in in `SQL`.
4. You are not supposed to SELECT the column `LAPSO_DOC`

You may better study some online articles on `PIVOT` - like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query) and [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

---

EDIT:

A coding standard

> ```
> NEVER declare a column name same as table name, and vice versa.
> ```

Comment: You are very right, a lot wrong with mine. I will definitely go study, MANY THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: Plus1  My hats off to you.  I didn't look beyond the table variable.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, sometimes :)

Answer (score 3):

It is a scope issue.

The table variable is not available to the dynamic sql

Perhaps drop it down to a temp table